# Old science fiction book about mutants / space opera

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel series that I read in the end of 1990s.

There are several novels in the series. Humanity left the Earth because of nuclear apocalypse. Humans inhabited several planets, but forgot where their original planet was located.

After several generations Earth was located. Earth is inhabited by mutants descendants of humans, I think there was about 4 species which had different abilities like mind reading, flying, strength etc.

After re-discovery of Earth it was terraformed again to remove nuclear contamination. Mutants were used afterwards in space crew according to their abilities. I think all 4 mutants kinds were included usually in space ship crew.

There are several stories about such crew adventures.